# List namevaluepair elements

Tags: android, list, foreach

I am developing an Android project and I have the following code segments which collects information into an "array":

```
//setup array containing submitted form data
ArrayList<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
data.add( new BasicNameValuePair("name", formName.getText().toString()) );
data.add( new BasicNameValuePair("test", "testing!") );


//send form data to CakeConnection
AsyncConnection connection = new AsyncConnection();
connection.execute(data);
```

My problem is how to read the individual members of that data list in my AsyncConnection class?

Answer (score 16):

You should simply iterate over the list to get access to each `NameValuePair`. With the `getName()` and `getValue()` methods you can retrieve the individual parameters of every pair.

```
for (NameValuePair nvp : data) {
    String name = nvp.getName();
    String value = nvp.getValue();
}
```